# AngularJS View not updating using UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="m in model">
    {{m.prop1}}{{m.prop2}}
</div>
```

inside controller is a deffered promise that fetches an object from the server.

```
promise.then(function(e){
    $scope.model.push(e); // e is an object, which is pushed into the array.
    $scope.$apply(); // causes digest already in progress error so put inside $timeout
});
```

I've tried **$timeout** and **$scope.$apply()** and the view still wont update:

```
var promise = ModelService.create(model,data);
promise.then(function(e){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.model.push(e);
        });
    })
});
```

Update: ModelService.js

```
create: function(model, data){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.post('/api/'+model+"/create", data).success(function(e){
                defer.resolve(e);
            }).error(function(e){
                defer.reject(e);
            });
            return defer.promise;
        }
```

any ideas to get the view to render the model update?

Comment: You don't need `$apply()` or `$timeout`. Is `e` the object in the correct structure that you're expecting?

Comment: `console.log(e)` to verify your object

Comment: Yes e is the correct data, and it is pushed into the array as ive logged out the model after the push. its just the view thats not updating

Comment: Is the view in a directive or is it straightforward?

Comment: please post more details about `promise` definition.

Comment: The view is a `ui-view` using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router which shouldnt make a difference as other pushes and concatenations work as intended.

Comment: The thing that's broken does not seem to be in here... we need a bigger picture I'm afraid.

Comment: Does the update help at all.

Comment: I don't think so. There's Batarang, a chrome extension, very helpful for debugging. You can inspect (with dev tools) your `div` element that has the `ng-repeat` and then do `$scope.model` in console and you'll see what's in there. You could try that.

Comment: I've found the source of the problem. The form is inside a child ui-state which uses the same controller but i think its creating a new instance of it. so its updating the model on the scope of the wrong instance of the controller.

Comment: I've found the solution. In my ui-routing config, parentstate and childstate both declared using `ThisController` creating 2 seperate instances of the same controller. By passing `false` for the childstate controller it inherits its parent controller

Answer (score 0):

My problem was down to a controller problem and overlooked workings of `ui-router`

I had 2 states, `model` and `model.create`, I declared both of these to use the same controller `ModelController`.

When on `ui-view` for model.create it created a new instance of `ModelController`

This meant that I was pushing the returned data into an array that wasnt rendered as it was rendered on the parent states instance of the controller.

**To fix** I passed false for the controller parameter of the child state causing it to use the same instance as the parent state and update the correct array.